# Spring managed JSF beans

Tags: spring, jsf, managed-bean

I am using Spring managed JSF beans, now do i have to use annotation tags Ex.@scope of spring or of JSF ?

I noticed that @ViewScoped which is JSF annotation not working and still behaving as request scope ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver` for Spring + JSF integration, then you need to to mark scope with `org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no View scope in Spring, but we can custom implement such scope.Refer [this](http://www.jroller.com/RickHigh/entry/adding_a_jsf_view_scope) or [this](http://comdynamics.net/blog/109/spring3-jsf2-view-scope/)

Answer (score 0):

Read this article: info in this article: http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/integrate-jsf-2-spring-3-nicely/

I did this:

Define an abstract superclass for JSF backing beans like this:

```
public abstract class AutowireableManagedBean {

    protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    protected AutowireCapableBeanFactory ctx;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        logger.debug("init");
        ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getWebApplicationContext(
                        (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                                .getExternalContext().getContext())
                .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        // The following line does the magic
        ctx.autowireBean(this);
    }
   ...
}
```

Then, make your backing beans extend that superclass and you will be able to autowire Spring beans and have make use of JSF-specific view scope:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBackingBean extends AutowireableManagedBean {

    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;
```